# Given $a^4+1=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\left(4b^2-b^4-1\right)$, find $a^4+b^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $$a^4+1=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\left(4b^2-b^4-1\right)$$
>   Find $$a^4+b^4$$

My approach:

- Verify for different values of $a$ and $b$ to see that question is correct and yes, it turns out to be $2$ always for different values of $a$ and $b$.
- Treat the entire thing as quadratic in $a^2$, find its solution using wolfram or manually, and eventually we get the value of $a^4+b^4$ to be $2$.

Any better solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this $$a^4+1=\frac{a^2}{b^2}(4b^2-b^4+1)$$?

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner yes

Comment: The only thing what i have found is$$-1+b^4+a^2\left(4+\frac{1}{b^2}-b^2\right)$$

Comment: Divide both side by $a^2$ and rearrange, one get
$$a^2 + \frac1{a^2} + b^2 + \frac{1}{b^2} = 4
\iff \left(a - \frac1a\right)^2 + \left(b-\frac1b\right)^2 = 0$$
This forces $a^2 = b^2 = 1 \implies a^4 + b^4 = 2$.

Comment: Very nice - but it's a pity that a and b real was not specified.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that we always have $a^4+b^4=2$. We can rewrite the equation as
$$
\left( a-\frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left( b-\frac{1}{b}\right)^2=0.
$$
Now chose $a$ such that $a-1/a=i$ and $b-1/b=1$, i.e., with $a := \sqrt{ - \sqrt{3}i + 1}/\sqrt{2}$ and $b=(\sqrt{5} + 1)/2$. This comes from solving the quadratic equations $a^2-ia-1=0$ and $b^2-b-1=0$.

Then we have $i^2+1^2=0$ above satisfied and
$$
a^4+b^4=\frac{3\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{3}i + 6}{2}\neq 2.
$$

For real numbers we obtain $a^2=b^2=1$, hence $a^4+b^4=2$.